# Merge two columns into one keeping hierarchical structure using pandas or excel writer

Tags: excel, pandas

I need to collapse two columns into one preserving hierarchical structure of the rest either using pandas or pandas and excel writer. I need to transform this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [ 'p', 'p', 'q'], 'B': ['x', 'y', 'z'], 'C': [1, 2, 3]})
df

    A   B   C
0   p   x   1
1   p   y   2
2   q   z   3
```

To this:

```
    A   C
0   p   
1   x   1
2   y   2
3   q   
4   z   3
```

UPD.
Thank you for your help. I edited my question and added more details.

Comment: Please check edited my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need:

```
df1 = df.stack().drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True).to_frame(name='A')
print (df1)
   A
0  p
1  x
2  y
3  q
4  z
```

Detail:

```
print (df.stack())
0  A    p
   B    x
1  A    p
   B    y
2  A    q
   B    z
dtype: object

print (df.stack().drop_duplicates())
0  A    p
   B    x
1  B    y
2  A    q
   B    z
dtype: object
```

Or if need remove duplicates only in first column is possible replace them by `NaN`s and `stack` function remove this rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [ 'p', 'p', 'q'], 'B': ['x', 'z', 'z']})
print (df)
   A  B
0  p  x
1  p  z
2  q  z

df['A'] = df['A'].mask(df['A'].duplicated())
df = df.stack().reset_index(drop=True).to_frame(name='A')
print (df)
   A
0  p
1  x
2  z
3  q
4  z
```

Detail:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].mask(df['A'].duplicated())
print (df)
     A  B
0    p  x
1  NaN  y
2    q  z
```

EDIT:

```
df1 = (df.set_index('C')
         .stack()
         .reset_index(name='A')
         .drop('level_1', 1)
         .drop_duplicates('A')[['A','C']])
df1['C'] = df1['C'].mask(df1['A'].isin(df['A']), '')
print (df1)
   A  C
0  p   
1  x  1
3  y  2
4  q   
5  z  3
```

Comment: `df.stack().drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True).to_frame(name='A')` for dataframe with column A

Answer (score 0):

Use `stack` as mentioned above.

Alternatively,

```
In [5443]: _, idx = np.unique(df, return_index=True)

In [5444]: pd.DataFrame({'A': df.values.flatten()[np.sort(idx)]})
Out[5444]:
   A
0  p
1  x
2  y
3  q
4  z
```